# Clock impulse through push button

Tags: digital-logic, clock

I need to store 4 bits in a shift register giving input through a push button. For which I also want to generate a clock pulse with the same push button with some delay(<100ms) so that the clock goes after the input. I cant figure out the delay circuit..

Comment: You need to explain what are you doing and why you need this. Reading your question I would say you do not need a register at all, but 100ms delay circuit.

Comment: After edit it also sounds wrong. What is "input"? Key press and release? If only key press is an input, then your shift register will always be filled with same value (so no need in it), if "input" means press and release, then your shift register will always have 0101 or 1010 in it. Voting to close as unclear unless you say what exactly you want to get and why.

Comment: totally unclear what you are describing .... i hope that it is really clear in your mind, because you cannot write the code until it is crystal clear in your head.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMBvYo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Many choices. These are two of them.  The Schmitt trigger type inputs prevent contact bounce and noise glitches.  Pulse width is approximately T=RC but dont make C too big otherwise current discharge may arc contact plating or pit carbon. Then a series 100 Ohm R may be appropriate.

Switch bounce varies from 1ms to 100ms depending on bulk size or quality.

Depending on purpose, you may use leading active edge or trailing or the state for Reset, (POR).

CLK_B must never be used from a separate Vcc in case of power sequence latchup fault , otherwise prevent occurence by extra clamp diodes as ESD diodes are intended for only Q=CV=3kV*100pF= 300uC.

Vcc may be anything that the CMOS is rated for.